# "Go to method in current file" feature in Visual Studio 17.9 is now missing (regression)

Tags: visual-studio, search

Since Visual Studio 17.9, Microsoft removed the possibility to locate a method or a member in the current file.
Or am I missing something?
In previous Visual Studio, this is what I could do:
Ctrl+T, then start typing the method or member name.

The new Ctrl+T from Microsoft can only locate members in the WHOLE SOLUTION.
I need to find a member in the current file only.